# Вывод значения в формулу из оператора сравнения

Tags: javascript, калькулятор

Ребята я новичок. Задача вывести определенное значение из оператора сравнения в формулу. 0-100=550, 101-300=450, 301-500=400, 501+ =350

```
function gipsToRangeId(tolsina) {
    tolsina = parseInt(tolsina);
    if (tolsina <= 0)
      return 550;
    else if (tolsina <= 100)
      return 550;
    else if (tolsina <= 301)
      return 450;
    else if (tolsina <= 500)
      return 400;
    else
      return 350;
  }
```

Сама формула для вывода значения : var range.value = (указываем в input)

```
var cafgips = gipsToRangeId(tolsina);

var sum = (range.value * cafgips);
out.innerHTML = sum;
```

Выдает не правильно. Например range.value = 200. (200 х gipsToRangeId(tolsina)) = должно быть 90.000 Так как 200 < 301 следовательно = коэффициенту 450 а не 550 ... Подскажите в чем ошибка ?

Код целиком

```
var btn = document.querySelector('#btn'),
    out = document.querySelector('#out'),
    load = document.querySelector('#load'),
    del = document.querySelector('#del'),
    range = document.querySelector('#range'),
    rasstoyanie = document.querySelector('.rasstoyanie').innerHTML = 1;
    tolsina = document.querySelector('.tolsina').innerHTML = 1;
    


// Function calc gips
function gipsToRangeId(rasstoyanie) {
  rasstoyanie = parseInt(rasstoyanie);
    if (rasstoyanie <= 0)
      return 550;
    else if (rasstoyanie <= 100)
      return 550;
    else if (rasstoyanie <= 301)
      return 450;
    else if (rasstoyanie <= 500)
      return 400;
    else
      return 350;
  }


  // Function calc cement
function cementToRangeId(tolsina) {
    tolsina = parseInt(tolsina);
    if (tolsina <= 0)
      return 0;
    else if (tolsina <= 2)
      return 1;
    else if (tolsina <= 4)
      return 2;
    else if (tolsina <= 6)
      return 3;
    else if (tolsina <= 8)
      return 4;
    else if (tolsina <= 10)
      return 5;    
    else
      return 6;
  }




// Polzunok
function fun1() {
    var rng = document.getElementById('range');
    var p = document.getElementById('one');
    p.innerHTML = rng.value;
}

function fun2() {
    var rng = document.getElementById('range2');
    var p = document.getElementById('two');
    p.innerHTML = rng.value;
}

// range slider
range.onchange = function () {
    var rasstoyanie = document.querySelector('.rasstoyanie').innerHTML = range.value;
}
```

Comment: В приведенной функции ошибки нет, для 200 выдает 450. Значит изначально в переменной 'tolsina' не 200...

Comment: первый if можно убрать и у вас ошибка для 301.

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1239750

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var cafgips = gipsToRangeId(document.querySelector('.rasstoyanie').innerHTML);
```